# libgdx and motion actions

Tags: android, action, libgdx

I want to create some game, but I have a problem. I want to draw two images. I used Texture and SpriteBatch to draw two images. But now I want to implement some actions. I want to create messege for user. If he click on first image he gets message: your choice is picture1. And for the other image algorithm is the same.

```
public void create() {
    background = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("backg.png"));
    polishFlag = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("german.png"));
    englishFlag = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("english.png"));
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
}
public void render() {
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(background, 0, 0, 480, 320);
    batch.draw(germanFlag, 140,80, 90, 60);
    batch.draw(englishFlag, 260,80, 90, 60);
    batch.end();
}
```

How I can implement this functionality? I want to this solution work on android platform. Some ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the InputProcessor interface. (Alternatively, use an InputMultiplexer class).

Using an InputProcessor you could do something like:

```
public class YourGame implements InputProcessor{
      com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle touchBounds;
      string message ;
      BitmapFont font;

      //lots of input processor methods
      @Override
      public boolean onTouchDown(x, y, int button){
          tocuhBounds.x = 140;
          if (rectangle.contains(x,y))
               message = "your choice is picture1";
          else{
              touchBounds.x = 260;
              if (rectangle.contains(x,y))
                message = "your choice is picture2";
          }
      }

      public void create() {
             background = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("backg.png"));
             polishFlag = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("german.png"));
             englishFlag = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("english.png"));
             batch = new SpriteBatch();
             touchBounds = new Rectangle();
             touchBounds.width = 90;
             touchBounds.height = 60;
             touchBounds.y = 80;
             font = new BitmapFont();
      }

      public void render() {
          batch.begin();
          batch.draw(background, 0, 0, 480, 320);
          batch.draw(germanFlag, 140,80, 90, 60);
          batch.draw(englishFlag, 260,80, 90, 60);
          font.draw(batch, message, 10, 10);
          batch.end();
     }

}
```